# Same base of code for different iOS apps, same project

Tags: ios, architecture

I'm working in a project for two different companies that has the exact same project, differing only visually, but sharing all the backend code.

Is it possible to create, let's say, a target with a different icon, environment variables, assets catalog, bundle ID, etc, and use the same base for both apps?

Or is it a better approach to create a framework and duplicate the projects, then use the frameworks?

Comment: Yes, it possible

Comment: With multi target

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/

Answer (score 1):

Create a target with different icon , bundle Id and same code is better as creating a framework will lead to a problem if you are using pods or other third party frameworks as with the second approcah nested frameworks are not allowed in ios apps

Comment: I've seen the link that you provided. Thank you. It seems a little difficult in my case because, Icons are the same, but their colors differ from each other. I don't know if this is possible.